# Trying to use an input box in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get values to use in my code using an input box but it starts giving me bugs when I add this in.

```
Sub pipe_size()

Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant
Dim NPS As Variant
Dim Sch As Variant
Dim z As Single
Dim i As Single
Dim a As Variant
Dim j As Integer
Dim msg As String
Dim b As Variant

'NPS = InputBox("Enter Nominal Pipe Size(inches)", "Nominal Pipe Size")
'Sch = InputBox("Enter Schedule Number", "Pipe Schedule")

NPS = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R35").Value
Sch = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R36").Value
'x is column number, y is row number
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(NPS, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Q5:Q33"), 0)
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sch, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R3:AD3"), 0)

'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Y34").Value = Sch
'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Y35").Value = x
'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Y36").Value = y

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AI1:AI13").Clear
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E4").Clear

For i = 1 To 13
a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R5:AD33"), x, i)
If a > 0 Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AI" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R3:AD33"), 1, i)
Else: End If
Next i

z = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R5:AD33"), x, y)
If z > 0 Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Y37").Value = z
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E4").Value = z
ElseIf z = 0 Then
MsgBox ("This pipe schedule does not exist for this pipe size")
msg = "The following schedules exist for this pipe size:" & vbCrLf

For j = 1 To 13
b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("AI" & j)
If b > 0 Then
msg = msg & vbCrLf & b

Else: End If

Next j

MsgBox msg

Else: End If


End Sub
```

The code runs fine when it gets the values for NPS and Sch from a  cell but  when I try to use an input box to give the values, it finds type mismatches and errors in the workbookfunctions.

Comment: In that case use Application.InputBox instead of InputBox and specify the data type within Type:= argument.

Comment: Are you sure a match was found? You will get that kind of errors if nothing was found. Also keep in mind that for `MATCH` numerical `1` is not the same as the string-`1`. Hint: better use `Application.Match` because you will get an error in return instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` which will pop up VBA-errors.

Comment: Yes a match was found when I did the same thing without using the input box(directly getting the Sch from a cell). I think that's the problem that its  reading a string and the next part uses a numerical one. Is there any way I can make them both the same? Can match read a string and find that? And then later use the string in my index function?

Answer (score 0):

Use Application.InputBox like below...

```
NPS = Application.InputBox("Enter Nominal Pipe Size(inches)", "Nominal Pipe Size", Type:=1) 'Type:=1 means Numeric input
Sch = InputBox("Enter Schedule Number", "Pipe Schedule", Type:=2) 'Type:=2 means String input
```

Change the Type as per your requirement.

OR

You can use Range.Find like below...

```
Dim rng As Range
Sch = Application.InputBox("Enter Schedule Number", "Pipe Schedule", Type:=2)
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R3:AD3").Find(Sch)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    y = rng.Column - 17
    MsgBox y
End If
```

Comment: It seems to work for x as NPS can only be a numeric input however it puts a problem in the y line. `y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sch, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R3:AD3"), 0)`. The error is "unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class.

Comment: What is the data type of Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R36")?

Comment: And what Type you used in Application.InputBox for Sch?

Comment: Make sure that the data type of Sch and data type in the range R3:AD3 are exactly same.

Comment: My problem I think is that Sch can be letters or numbers (due to industry code) and that is what messes up the code. The range R3:AD3 is a mix of numbers or letters that correspond to possible values of Sch. I need the match function to return the column number of the selected Sch as a number but that's where it is glitching out. Any ideas?

Comment: In that case you can use Find instead of Match. See the edited solution.

Comment: I'm using the match function to get the column number of which that particular Sch is. I don't believe the find function provides that.